# how to merge a foreach loop with a while loop to build an html table?

Tags: php, sql, foreach

i have two arrays $_SESSION['fff'] which have the quantity and the other is $result which is extracted from mysql database including the name of the product, price and weight, i need to build a table which includes the data from the database and the quantity which is included in the session variable array

```
$wherein = implode(",", $_SESSION['cart']);
$sql = "select id, item_name, Price, Weight from items where id IN 
($wherein)";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<table style='width:100%' border='1' >";
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th> Product Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Product Price </th>" ;
    echo "<th>Weight </th>" ;
    echo "<th>Quantity </th>" ;


    echo "</tr>";
 $sum = '';
 $s= '';
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))) && 
foreach($_SESSION['fff'] as $value){
$sum += $row['Price'];
$s += $row['Weight']; 

echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> $". $row['Price'] . "</td>" ;






    echo "<td>". $row['Weight'] ; 









    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";




    }
```

I have been trying for hours now searching online and trying different ways but couldn't get to a solution. Thank you.

Comment: You can't "merge" the loops like this, something is wrong with your logic if you're finding the need for this. Can you describe how it SHOULD work a bit so we can help find the solution?

Comment: i have two arrays $_SESSION['fff'] which have the quantity and the other is $result which is extracted from mysql database including the name of the product, price and weight, i need to build a table which includes the data from the database and the quantity which is included in the session variable array

Comment: How is the data in $_SESSION['fff'] linked to the data in the result set?

Comment: it is not linked

Comment: So then how do you know which value in $_SESSION['fff'] should be displayed with each row from the result set? Do you just want random items from $_SESSION['fff'] displayed with each row? Or what?

Comment: it will be according to order in the array

Comment: they both have the same order in the array and the same count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allocate session value to variable like

```
$session_var = $_SESSION['fff'];
```

Don`t Use foreach()
Declare variable

```
$i=0; 
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
{
$sum += $row['Price'];
$s += $row['Weight']; 
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['item_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> $". $row['Price'] . "</td>" ;
    echo "<td>". $row['Weight'] ; 
    echo "<td>".$session_var[$i]."</td>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
for($i = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $i++) {
    // access rows using $row
    // access corresponding session data using $_SESSION['fff'][$i]
}
```

If your array keys in $_SESSION['fff'] are not numeric, add the following before the loop:

```
$session = array_values($_SESSION['fff']);
```

Then access values using `$session[$i]` within the loop.